# Find consecutive number of 1's

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the number of consecutive 1's in a binary.

Example: Convert Decimal number to Binary and find consecutive 1's

```
static int count = 0;
static int max = 0;
static int index = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    String b = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    char[] arr = b.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
        if (arr[i] == index) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }

        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max);
}
```

I am always getting 0. It seems as if the condition is not working in my code. Could you please provide your suggestion on where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: The character `'1'`, when converted to an `int`, does not have the value `1`, so `arr[i] == index` is never going to be true.  Instead you want `index` to be a char with the value `'1'`.

Comment: **SUGGESTION**: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and examine all interim values along the way.

Comment: Thanks @azurefrog i have changed the datatype of index to char. Its working fine now.

Comment: @Karthik Consider deleting your question now.

Comment: Do you want the int binary or uint binary?...eg in int binary for -1 is all 1s

Answer (score 2):

Your qusetion is not so clear but AFAIU from your algorithm, you're trying to find number of most repeated 1's. The issue is that when you're doing comparision `if (arr[i] == index)`, the comparison is done with a char and integer because type of arr is char array. Isn't it? To overcome it either you can convert the `char array` into integer or convert the integer `index` value into `char`. I do this to overcome it.

```
if (arr[i] == index + '0')
```

It is not an really elegant solution. I assume that you're a student and want you to show what's wrong. If I want to do something like this, I use,

```
private static int maxConsecutiveOnes(int x) {
        // Initialize result
        int count = 0;

        // Count the number of iterations to
        // reach x = 0.
        while (x!=0) {
            // This operation reduces length
            // of every sequence of 1s by one.
            x = (x & (x << 1));

            count++;
        }

        return count;
}
```

Its trick is,

```
      11101111   (x)
    & 11011110   (x << 1)
    ----------
      11001110   (x & (x << 1)) 
        ^    ^
        |    |
   trailing 1 removed
```

Comment: I like this one with bits!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand correctly, you want to count maximum length of the group of `1` in the binary representation of the `int` value. E.g. for `7917=0b1111011101101` result will be `4` (we have following groups of `1`: 1, 2, 3, 4).

You could use bit operations (and avoid to string convertation). You have one counter (to count amount of `1` in the current group) and `max` with maximum of all such amounts. All you need is just to check lowest bit for `1` and then rotate value to the right until it becomes `0`, like `getMaxConsecutiveSetBit1`.

Or just do it in a very simple way - convert it to the binary string and count amount of `1` characters in it, like `getMaxConsecutiveSetBit2`. Also have one counter + max. Do not forget, that `char` in Java is an `int` on the JVM level. So you do not have compilation problem with compare `char` with `int` value `1`, but this is wrong. To check if character is `1`, you have to use character - `'1'`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int val = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(val));
        System.out.println(getMaxConsecutiveSetBit1(val));
        System.out.println(getMaxConsecutiveSetBit2(val));
    }
}

public static int getMaxConsecutiveSetBit1(int val) {
    int max = 0;
    int cur = 0;

    while (val != 0) {
        if ((val & 0x1) != 0)
            cur++;
        else {
            max = Math.max(max, cur);
            cur = 0;
        }

        val >>>= 1;
    }

    return Math.max(max, cur);
}

public static int getMaxConsecutiveSetBit2(int val) {
    int max = 0;
    int cur = 0;

    for (char ch : Integer.toBinaryString(val).toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == '1')
            cur++;
        else {
            max = Math.max(max, cur);
            cur = 0;
        }
    }

    return Math.max(max, cur);
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. They wrote "*consecutive* 1's". The answer to 0b11011 is 2 because the max is two consecutive 1's.

Answer (score 1):

Change type of `index` variable from `int` to `char`:

`static char index = 1;`

to let the comparison made in this line:

```
if (arr[i] == index)
```

do its job. Comparing `int 1` (in your code this is the value stored in `index` variable) with  `char '1'` (in your example it's currently checked element of `arr[]`) checks if ASCII code of given `char` is equal to `int` value of 1. This comparison is never true as char '1' has an ASCII code 49 and this is the value that is being compared to value of 1 (49 is never equal to 1).

You might want to have a look at ASCII codes table in the web to see that all characters there have assigned corresponding numeric values. You need to be aware that these values are taken into consideration when comparing `char` to `int` with `==` operaror.

When you change mentioned type of `index` to `char`, comparison works fine and your code seems to be fixed.

Comment: Does this one change fix the entire program? If it doesn't, then this should be a comment. If it does, please be more explicit in your answer so I can upvote you and they can mark you correct.

Comment: @DavidS Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to improve my answer and I  hope  you take a look at it if it meets your requirements now.

Comment: In that case this might be the best answer for Karthik. She is very likely a beginning programmer working on a homework assignment, so I don't feel jumping to bit operations (like some of the other answers do) is  appropriate.

Comment: @DavidS I think that in case of Karthik it can be the most helpful answer, but we should also be aware that this question might be searched by more experienced users looking for a more complex or more efficient solution of the same problem in the future, so I think it is a good place to put more complex solutions here too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using your for loop structure and changing a few things around while also adding some other stats to report which could be useful. I count the total number of 1's in the number, the number of consecutive 1's (groups of 1's), and the greatest number of consecutive 1's. Also your for loop was looping based on the string length and not the array's length which is just sort of nit picky. Here is the code

```
int count = 0;
int max = 0;
char index = '1';
int consecutiveOnePairs = 0;
int numberOfOnes = 0;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scan.nextInt();
String b = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
char[] arr = b.toCharArray();
System.out.println(arr);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == index)
    {
        count++;
        numberOfOnes++;
    }

    if((i + 1 == arr.length && count > 1) || arr[i] != index)
    {
        if(count > 1)
            consecutiveOnePairs++;
        if (count > max)
            max = count;
        count = 0;
    }
}

System.out.println("Total Number of 1's in " + n + " is " + numberOfOnes);
System.out.println("Total Number of Consecutive 1's in " + n + " is " + consecutiveOnePairs);
System.out.println("Greatest Number of Consecutive 1's in " + n + " is " + max);
scan.close();
```

**Output**

```
13247
11001110111111
Total Number of 1's in 13247 is 11
Total Number of Consecutive 1's in 13247 is 3
Greatest Number of Consecutive 1's in 13247 is 6

511
111111111
Total Number of 1's in 511 is 9
Total Number of Consecutive 1's in 511 is 1
Greatest Number of Consecutive 1's in 511 is 9

887
1101110111
Total Number of 1's in 887 is 8
Total Number of Consecutive 1's in 887 is 3
Greatest Number of Consecutive 1's in 887 is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8, you can try this snippet:

```
 public int maxOneConsecutive(int x)
  {
    String intAsBinaryStr = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
    String[] split = intAsBinaryStr.split("0");
    return Arrays.stream(split)
        .filter(str -> !str.isEmpty())
        .map(String::length)
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a)).orElse(0);
  }
```